# how to launch application launcher via latte dock using only Super key?

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, dock

[image]I want to open latte dock using only super key.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [FAQ page of the project on GitHub](https://github.com/psifidotos/Latte-Dock/wiki/F.A.Q.#q-can-i-use-my-super-key-to-open-the-app-launcher), there are two ways to do this.

You can either edit `~/.config/kwinrc` and add

```
[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
Meta=org.kde.lattedock,/Latte,org.kde.LatteDock,activateLauncherMenu
```

or run the following commands in terminal

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta "org.kde.lattedock,/Latte,org.kde.LatteDock,activateLauncherMenu"
```

then, in either case, reload KWin:

```
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

Comment: Do you have a command to undo this and let kde plasma panels handle the super key

Comment: xcodz-dot you should be able to just go into `~/.config/kwinrc` and remove the two lines shown in the prompt above. Don't forget to reload KWin to apply!