# How to make windows button alone to open Main menu in KDE?

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, kde

Is it possible to make windows button alone to open Main menu in KDE?

[image]

If I am trying to do this with standard settings dialog, it waits for some additional key to be pressed.

Comment: Using the Windows button / super key works by default in Kubuntu 18.04. What is different about your configuration?

Comment: @NathanielM.Beaver did you try to enter it in configuration window I showed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate application launcher using meta key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087909/how-to-activate-application-launcher-using-meta-key)

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** After some help from @DKBose I am 90% sure this is a duplicate of an older question:

[How to activate application launcher using meta key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087909/how-to-activate-application-launcher-using-meta-key)

Relevant excerpts:

> Turned out I had modified the file ~/.config/kwinrc when I installed Latte
>   dock and after I removed it, the meta key was no longer activating Plasma's
>   application launcher.
>
> To enable it again open ~/.config/kwinrc and update the following section:
>
> ```
> [ModifierOnlyShortcuts]
> Meta=org.kde.plasmashell,/PlasmaShell,org.kde.PlasmaShell,activateLauncherMenu
> ```
>
> [ . . . ]
>
> Interesting! I don't have the `[ModifierOnlyShortcuts]` section in my
>   `~/.config/kwinrc` (Kubuntu 18.04) and the meta key works to activate the
>   launcher.

and from the
[linked forum post](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74673-Disable-the-Windows-Key-Popping-up-Launcher?p=422438&viewfull=1#post422438):

> You can try this oneliner:
>   Code:
>
> ```
> kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""
> ```
>
> (it writes a config key in ~/.config/kwinrc that should prevent the meta key
>   from opening the launcher...you may need to re-login into plasma for this to
>   take effect. )

Below is the original answer relating to the default behavior in 18.04.

**End of edit.**

[Plasma 5.8 and later exhibits this behavior by default](https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.7.5-5.8.0-changelog.php).
If you have Plasma 5.8 or later installed
and the Super/Meta/Windows key does not open the application launcher,
this is because of an old configuration file.

As [discussed in an older question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037647/get-super-windows-key-working-again-on-kubuntu-18-04),
if you have mapped it to something else,
setting the shortcut key to `Alt-F1`
automatically enables the super key
as a shortcut to open the application launcher.
Here it is for kickoff (a.k.a. Application Launcher):

[image: Application Launcher Settings, Keyboard shortcuts]

and here it is for kicker (a.k.a. Application Menu):

[image: Application Menu Settings, Keyboard shortcuts]

I have verified that this works for both on my machine running 18.04. It looks like you are using kicker, so you should be able to enable this behavior on your machine.

This feature was announced at the time:

> Thanks to our Wayland effort, we can finally offer so-called “modifier-only
>   shortcuts”, enabling you to open the application menu by just pressing the
>   Meta key. Due to popular demand, this feature also got backported to the X11
>   session.

https://kde.org/announcements/plasma-5.8.0.php

> Today I’m happy to announce that for the first time we were able to backport
>   a new feature from our Wayland offerings to X11: modifier only shortcut
>   support. This is one of the most often requested features in Plasma and I’m
>   very happy that we finally have an implementation for it.
>
> Modifier only shortcuts mean that an action is triggered if one clicks a
>   modifier key without any other key. By default the Meta (also known as super
>   and windows) key triggers the main application launcher of your Plasma
>   session. But the implementation is way more flexible and allows to use any
>   modifier (ctrl, alt or shift) as a trigger for an action (currently
>   configuration is only possible through manual modification of kwinrc).

https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2016/08/modifier-only-shortcuts-available-in-plasma-5-8/

Here are the commits in August 2016 that added this:

> Launch Plasma's launcher menu on meta modifier only shortcut by default
>
> Invokes org.kde.plasmashell /PlasmaShell org.kde.PlasmaShell.activateLauncherMenu.

https://phabricator.kde.org/D2357

https://github.com/KDE/kwin/commit/9b30cfef1d212ed2b40510a70d1f92c497f44398

> Add a dbus call to activate the "main" application launcher
>
> ShellCorona provides a new DBus method "activateLauncherMenu". If that is
>   invoked it will look through all panels for an applet which has
>   X-Plasma-Provides with org.kde.plasma.launchermenu. If that also has a global
>   shortuct it gets activated and no further applet is searched.
>
> The idea behind this DBus call is to provide a way to KWin to activate the
>   main appliction launcher when the Meta key is pressed.

https://phabricator.kde.org/D2356

https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/commit/267b6a8dfb4ad3b4f9da010d2aeaeebec25c5c0f

Related:

- [How do I open the Application Launcher on KDE with just the meta ("Windows") key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246886/how-do-i-open-the-application-launcher-on-kde-with-just-the-meta-windows-key)
- [Kde use super key to show desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/850735/kde-use-super-key-to-show-desktop)
- [how to launch application launcher via latte dock using only Super key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976045/how-to-launch-application-launcher-via-latte-dock-using-only-super-key)
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=152924
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=89&t=39073
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=109635
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=39073
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=84602
- https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=90646
- https://github.com/hanschen/ksuperkey
- https://obviate.io/2012/03/08/kde-windows-key-to-open-kickoff-launcher/

Comment: I think the questioner seems to want to use the GUI indicated in the question. I'm guessing that that GUI is **not** meant for "modifier-only" shortcuts. For that one has to add a section to ~/.config/kwinrc as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087909/how-to-activate-application-launcher-using-meta-key/1087910#1087910) and elsewhere or to run `kwriteconfig5 --file kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Meta ""`. And, as you pointed out, `Meta` does what is wanted by default unless something, not mentioned, has been done to disrupt that.

Comment: @DKBose Hm, interesting. I was able to get kicker / Application Menu working with just the Meta/Super key, and I don't see that section in my kwinrc. It seems more investigation is required. Edit: I see you having the same discussion on the other thread. Funny how things repeat sometimes.

Comment: The year 2021 is coming to a close, and none of these solutions work anymore.

Comment: @HilarieAK These solutions work fine for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Perhaps you could start a new question if you are using a different version?

Answer (score 1):

[image: 'Application Dashboard Settings ― Plasma' window]

In KDE 5.18 set <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> as shortcut (Meta key means Windows key)

after it work on just meta keypress